# How to unwrap angularjs resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

In angularjs, the `$resource` module (third type module) is awesome to fetch promised data (and so more).

for example if `Article` is a factory that return a `$resource` :

```
$scope.article = Article.query();
```

and you get a promise. When the promise is successfuly resolved, you get something like that:

```
> $scope.article;
[Resource, Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
0: Resource
1: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Great !

What I search is if exists a common method to unwrap the promise for some special tasks.

So, something like this :

```
> $resource.unwrap($scope.article);
[Array,Array]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

## NB :

> I don't search to code a function to implement the `unwrap` method, I already did it for my needs. I am looking for a 'native' way. However I it doesn't exist and someone as already coded a robust function to make it the right way, why not !

Comment: Why downvoting my question ?

Comment: Ok. Edit: I already did it for my needs. I am looking for a 'native' way. However if it doesn't exist and someone as already coded a robust function to make it the right way, why not !

Comment: *"I don't search to code a function to implement the unwrap method, I already did it."* include it so we don't do double work. Why is this needed? What is the purpose of, "unwrapping" it?

Comment: The purpose is getting the data privided by the ajax response, without the warping resource

Comment: But why? you can already get all of that data from the resource directly. you don't gain anything by unwrapping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably miss [some part of AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#credit-card-resource)

> You can also access the raw $http promise via the $promise property on the object returned

```
Article.query().$promise.then(function(articles) {
  $scope.articles = articles;
});
```

In the other hand, [AngularJS already provides method angular.toJson that removes all keys from object with $ as first character](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name angular.toJson
 * @module ng
 * @kind function
 *
 * @description
 * Serializes input into a JSON-formatted string. Properties with leading $ characters will be
 * stripped since angular uses this notation internally.
 *
 * @param {Object|Array|Date|string|number} obj Input to be serialized into JSON.
 * @param {boolean=} pretty If set to true, the JSON output will contain newlines and whitespace.
 * @returns {string|undefined} JSON-ified string representing `obj`.
 */
function toJson(obj, pretty) {
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined') return undefined;
  return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty ? '  ' : null);
}
```

and `toJsonReplacer` looks

```
function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
  var val = value;

  if (typeof key === 'string' && key.charAt(0) === '$') {
    val = undefined;
  } else if (isWindow(value)) {
    val = '$WINDOW';
  } else if (value &&  document === value) {
    val = '$DOCUMENT';
  } else if (isScope(value)) {
    val = '$SCOPE';
  }

  return val;
}
```

Comment: .toJson() fits perfectly my search. Thanks!